# In D&D 4e, does the half-elf get an extra encounter power, or does his race power take the place of his class power?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, half-elf

The half-elf gets a racial power that lets him take an at-will from a class not his own and make it an encounter power. Does that mean it replaces his class encounter power or that he gets an additional encounter power?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You seem to be talking about the Dilettante.  this does not replace anything.  It is a bonus Racial power. The first Player's Handbook has the details on page 42 as does Player Essentials: Heroes of the Forgotten Kingdoms on page 252.

If it replaced something the text would say it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I didn't think of it as a racial power, but I guess it's just like the dragonborn's breath attack. Thanks! And yes, I was thinking of Dilettante, but I couldn't remember the name.